# error missing script: nodemon

Tags: node.js, npm, nodemon

I was following tutorial that I have found [here](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2017/01/internationalizing-react-apps/). Previously the command was running fine, but after some changes when I run`npm run nodemon` it gives me error
[image]

Here is my package.json

```
{
  "name": "smashing-react-i18n",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "dist/bundle.js",
  "betterScripts": {
    "build": {
      "command": "webpack -p",
      "env": {
        "NODE_ENV": "production"
      }
    },
    "nodemon": {
      "command": "nodemon server.js",
      "env": {
        "NODE_PATH": "src"
      }
    }
  },
```

Comment: Shouldn't `betterScripts` be `scripts`?

Comment: @SimpleJ even with scripts the same error

Comment: Have you installed [better-npm-run](https://www.npmjs.com/package/better-npm-run) and tried running `better-npm-run nodemon`?

Comment: Did you install nodemon globally with `-g`?

Comment: after looking at original repo https://github.com/yury-dymov/smashing-react-i18n/blob/master/package.json i have found that scripts section is removed. i'm wondering i never changed package.json my self.